# How to use a while loop to help index/find a element that matches string statement

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I'm trying to create a function that takes a parameter, which is a country and locates the adjacent capital for the country. Ex:

```
countries_and_capitals = (['Afghanistan', 'Kabul'], ['Albania', 'Tirana (Tirane)'], ['Algeria', 'Algiers'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella'],
['Angola', 'Luanda'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', "Saint John's"], ['Argentina', 'Buenos Aires'],
['Armenia', 'Yerevan'],
['Australia', 'Canberra']

def get_capital_from_the_country(cntry)
```

And displays the capital after you input the country.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use a `for` loop and iterate over the tuple while unpacking both values (country and capital), then if a country is found that matches the argument, return the capital, if no country is found then return the message (this method is faster):

```py
countries_and_capitals = (['Afghanistan', 'Kabul'], ['Albania', 'Tirana (Tirane)'], ['Algeria', 'Algiers'], ['Andorra', 'Andorra la Vella'],
['Angola', 'Luanda'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', "Saint John's"], ['Argentina', 'Buenos Aires'],
['Armenia', 'Yerevan'],
['Australia', 'Canberra'])


def get_capital_from_the_country(cntry):
    cntry = cntry.lower()
    for country, capital in countries_and_capitals:
        if country.lower() == cntry:
            return capital
    return 'Can\'t find that country'


print(get_capital_from_the_country('Afghanistan'))
# Kabul
print(get_capital_from_the_country('Afghanista'))
# Can't find that country
print(get_capital_from_the_country('afghanistan'))
# Kabul
print(get_capital_from_the_country('aFgHaniStan'))
# Kabul
```

Another way would be to convert that tuple to a dictionary and then easily access the value (capital) of the key (country) by using `.get` (to return a specific message instead of raising a `KeyError`):

```py
def get_capital_from_the_country(cntry):
    dct = {k.lower(): w for k, w in countries_and_capitals}
    # alternatively can use:
    # dct = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0].lower(), x[1]), countries_and_capitals))
    return dct.get(cntry.lower(), 'Can\'t find that country')
```

Comment: Do you know how i could make this NON case sensitive?

Comment: @jump yes, I edited answer to include that

Comment: @jump Please see [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), this will help future readers and also allow to mark other questions as duplicates. Thank you!